# How to add translations to date using react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am using react-i18next for the first time and I want to translate the string of date format. how can I do it using react-i18next?

this is the format the date is in
Sat Jul 27 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300

how do I translate it into another language?
could someone help me with this? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can format a date like so in your translations

```
"key": "Current date: {{date, dd/MM/yyyy}}"
```

Have a look at the i18next official [docs](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting) about formatting.

You can initialise i18next providing a function for interpolation, like so;

```js
i18next.init({
  interpolation: {
    formatSeparator: ',',
    format: function(value, formatting, lng){
       if(value instanceof Date) return moment(value).format(formatting);
       return value.toString();
    }
  }
});
```

The result:

```
i18next.t('key', { date: new Date() }); // -> Current date: 13/07/2019
```

source: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/774#issuecomment-232396505